# How to create a new shapefile from JTS geometries?

Tags: shapefile, geotools, dbf, jts-topology-suite

What I use:
Java 1.7, JTS 1.13, geotools.api 14

What I have finished:
Creating correct JTS geometries from OSM relations, ways and nodes.

What I want to achieve:
Create a CSV file which contains the following data:
the_geom, name, postal_code, country, osm_id

"the_geom" should be a JTS polygon geometry or a null geometry.(Complains ESRI Specification)

The CSV file makes it possible to easy fill up data.

After those CSV file is completely created I want to read that file and create a shapefile from it. Those attributes like name, postal_code and so on, should be written into a dbf file related to new shapefile.

Following this I want to import the new shape and dbf file into PostgreSQL.

Next step to accomplish requirements written above:
How can I create a new shape and dbf file from any collection containing JTS polygon geometries? There are many classes involved but none of them is explained clearly in [geotools.org](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/feature/csv2shp.html#csv2shp) like creating file headers and so on.

Something like:

```
public class Shapefile
{
  public Shapefile(String filename)
  {
      //..creates necessary stuff
  }

  public void loadFromCSV(String filename, String delimiter)
  {
     //use addGeometry for each row in csv ...
  }

  public void addGeometry(Geometry g, int esriType, Map<String, String> attributes)
  {
     //esriType = 5 for polygons and so on....
     //attributes = attributes for dbf file. Like name, postal_code ...
  }

  public void write() throws IOException
  {
     //Writes output to shapefile and dbf file ...
  }
 }
```

I hope someone can explain it.

Comment: If you are coding with Java it may be interesting to see how OpenJUMP is reading OSM data with the JOSM library https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/OsmFileReaderPlugin/. It may not be easy to re-use the OJ shapefile writer in your own code but here seems to be a little bit similar example with BeanShell script http://ojwiki.soldin.de/index.php?title=Beanshell:Converting_JML_files_to_shapefiles.

Comment: Have you looked at GeoTools's csv2shp example? It should have all that you need: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html

I also second the OpenJUMP recommendation, writing Shapefiles is quite easy with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard and long winded way of doing it, you really should use GeoTools' [datastores](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) (which abstract all this work away)

So assuming that what you actually want is to write some geometries and attributes to PostGIS you can do this:

Decide what is in your dataset and convert your objects to Features (usually SimpleFeatures):

```
SimpleFeatureType schema = null;
try {
    schema = DataUtilities.createType("", "Location",
        "locations:LineString:srid=4326," + // <- the geometry
                        // attribute:
            "id:Integer" // a number attribute
         //add more attributes here to match your dataset
    );
} catch (SchemaException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(schema);
//for each feature you have do:
featureBuilder.add(geom);
featureBuilder.add(name);
featureBuilder.add(number);
//+ all the other attributes (probably use a loop)
SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
//put them into a collection feats and then convert it to a FeatureCollection
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(shpType,
                    feats);
```

Now you need a PostGIS datastore (or a CSV or ShapeFile if you prefer):

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put( "dbtype", "postgis");
params.put( "host", "localhost");
params.put( "port", 5432);
params.put( "schema", "public");
params.put( "database", "database");
params.put( "user", "postgres");
params.put( "passwd", "postgres");

DataStore dataStore=DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

String typeName = dataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore
                .getFeatureSource(typeName);
if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
            SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;


            featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
            try {
                List<FeatureId> ids = featureStore.addFeatures(collection);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception problem) {
                problem.printStackTrace();
                transaction.rollback();
            } finally {
                transaction.close();
            }
            dataStore.dispose();
            return true;
        }
```